# Haskell: mysterious "Error in array index" when using "putStr"

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to implement a solution for [this hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo/problem) in Haskell for fun.
Since hackerrank reads solutions from stdout, I output my answer using `putStr`.

Unfortunately, this yields a rather uninformative and difficult to track error: `Error in array index`

Here's the `main` function of the solution:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    mnrTemp <- getLine
    let mnr = L.words $ rstrip mnrTemp

    let m = read (mnr !! 0) :: Int

    let n = read (mnr !! 1) :: Int

    let r = read (mnr !! 2) :: Int

    matrixTemp <- readMultipleLinesAsStringArray m

    let raw_matrix = L.map (\x -> L.map (read :: String -> Int) . L.words $ rstrip x) matrixTemp

    let matrix = array ((0::Int, 0::Int), (n-1, m-1)) $ L.concat [ [ ((i,j), a)| (j, a) <- L.zip [0..] row] | (i, row) <- L.zip [0..] raw_matrix] :: Array (Int, Int) Int

    let rotated_matrix = matrixRotation matrix r
    putStr $ showMatrix rotated_matrix
```

Everything from the call to `readMultipleLinesAsStringArray` and up was provided as part of the skeleton of the solution.
Naturally, I assume that the bug lies sometime after that; likely in some array (`Data.Array`) access in `matrixRotation`, or, less likely, in `showMatrix`.

However, some print debugging seems to indicate otherwise. 
If I swap `putStr $ showMatrix` with `print`, I see the correct answer (albeit poorly formatted). This seems to rule out any errors in `matrixRotation`.
Further, if I swap `putStr` with `print`, I also see the correct answer (as a string, with quotes and newlines explicitly shown). This seems to rule out any errors in `showMatrix`.

Somehow, using `putStr` causes `Error in array index`, and I'm not sure how to identify where this happens.

Here's the rest of my solution, in case there are any obvious problems there:

- Default imports and language extensions for the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Data.Array
import Data.Bits
import Data.List as L
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Set
import Data.Text
import Debug.Trace
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Control.DeepSeq
```

- My `showMatrix` implementation:

```
showMatrix :: Array (Int, Int) Int -> String
showMatrix matrix =
    let ((min_row, min_col), (max_row, max_col)) = bounds matrix
        row_major_order m = [ [show $ m!(i,j) | j <- [min_col..max_col]] | i <- [min_row..max_row]]
    in L.intercalate "\n" . L.map (L.intercalate " ") . row_major_order $ matrix
```

- my `matrixRotation` solution

```
-- Complete the matrixRotation function below.
matrixRotation :: Array (Int, Int) Int -> Int -> Array (Int, Int) Int
matrixRotation matrix r =
    let (max_row_ix, max_col_ix) = snd $ bounds matrix :: (Int, Int)
        (n, m) = (max_row_ix + 1, max_col_ix + 1)
        num_squares = n `div` 2

        rotated_square k =
            let (max_row_k, max_col_k) = (max_row_ix-k, max_col_ix-k)
                top = L.zip (repeat k) [k+1..max_row_k-1]
                bot = L.zip (repeat max_row_k) [k+1..max_row_k-1]
                left = L.zip [k+1..max_row_k-1] (repeat k)
                right = L.zip [k+1..max_row_k-1] (repeat max_col_k)
                corners = [(k,k), (k, max_col_k), (max_row_k, k), (max_row_k, max_col_k)]
                square_domain = top ++ bot ++ left ++ right ++ corners
            in [((i,j), rotated_elem (i,j) k) | (i,j) <- square_domain]


        rotated_elem :: (Int, Int) -> Int -> Int
        rotated_elem (i,j) k =
            let (max_row_k, max_col_k) = (max_row_ix-k, max_col_ix-k) in

            -- handle corners first
            -- top left => read from right
            if i == k && j == k then matrix!(i,j+1)
            -- top right => read from bottom 
            else if i == k && j == max_col_k then matrix!(i+1,j)
            -- bottom left => read from top
            else if i == max_row_k && j == k then matrix!(i-1,j)
            -- bottom right => read from left
            else if i == max_row_k && j == max_col_k then matrix!(i,j-1)
            else
                -- top row => read from right
                if i == k then matrix!(i, j+1)
                -- bottom row => read from left
                else if i == max_row_k then matrix!(i, j-1)
                -- left col => read from top
                else if j == k then matrix!(i-1,j)
                -- right col => read from bot
                else if j == max_col_k then matrix!(i+1,j)
                else error "ERROR"
                --else error "index " ++ show (i,j) ++ " not in " ++ show k ++ "th square " 
        rotated_matrix :: Array (Int, Int) Int
        rotated_matrix = matrix // L.concat [rotated_square k | k <- [0..num_squares-1]]
        in if r <= 0 then matrix
        else if r == 1 then rotated_matrix
        else matrixRotation rotated_matrix (r-1)
```

Comment: I don’t think putStr has anything to do with the error. Did you notice what line throws it?

Comment: The only error information I can see is literally: `Error in array index`. No mention of which index or which line number. Even worse, no exception is thrown, so I can't use `try` or `catch`.

Comment: Correction: turns out I can `catch` a generic `SomeException`, but it only seems to hold the info `Error in array index`

Comment: Probably `putStr` triggers the evaluation of some thunk, which was created because of laziness. I forgot how to debug such issues, but I'd have a look at `HasCallStack` and/or profiling options, which can instrument the code to generate proper stack traces. I recall this being far from trivial, unfortunately.

Comment: You can get stack traces by compiling with the GHC options `-prof -fprof-auto` and then running with `+RTS -xc`. See also this [relevant section in the GHC user manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-flag--xc).

Comment: Just as a side note, `!!` almost always indicates a poor data structure and/or algorithm choice.

Comment: The usage of `!!` was provided as part of the IO skeleton of the solution.
Also, the fact that the solution function skeleton is presented as an empty `do` block, rather than as a pure function, makes me think hackerrank doesn't grok Haskell too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `let matrix = ...` line, you've flipped the roles for `n` and `m`, so it crashes on asymmetric matrices.  You want:

```
... = array ((0::Int,0::Int), (m-1,n-1)) ...
                               ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Now I can get into finding logic errors.